# Query SID using WMIC and set to variabe in batch file

Tags: batch-file, csv, migration, wmic, sid

I am writing a user migration script from server 2008 to server 2008 R2. I've got most of the script written, however I'm stuck retrieving the SID for the registry export of the user. so far I have:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%B IN (D:\users\$userprofile%\desktop\user.txt) do SET userx=%%B
echo %userx%
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in  ('WMIC useraccount WHERE name='%userx%' get 
sid /format:csv') DO SET usersid=%%A
echo %usersid%
```

I'm currently testing this piece so user.txt just contains my name, but the .txt will later be populated with users to be migrated. Currently the code returns

```
dgibbons - Invalid alias verb.
```

The WMIC command works just fine. Searches on the invalid alias verb error all point to a space after name = (as in name= '%userx%'). Removing the variable (leaving the WMIC cmd in the for loop) and inserting my username still returns the same error. I have also tried with double, single and no quotes, each returning the same error. It seems the issue is the for loop is creating a space before the username; that's my take on it anyways. Anyone have any idea on how to make the code work?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in  ('"WMIC useraccount WHERE name='%username%' get sid /format:csv"') DO (
    SET usersid=%%A
)
echo %usersid%
```

The problem is in `=` sign which is a standard delimiter and in this case acts as space.The most convenient way to fix this according to me is using double quotes inside the single ones. Also can be escaped with `^=` , but makes code a little bit unreadable.